# Change route order in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to have the following URL route in my application: `/:username/:resource_name`. So, when I type `http://www.mywebsite.com/john/apple`, it will load the resource called `apple` that belongs to `john`. If `john` or `apple` don't exist, it will show a message saying that the user or the resource doesn't exist.

When I create that route, it goes to the top of the routes list (`rake routes`). And in this way, it gets confused with other routes, such as `/users/sign_in`, and it says that the resource `sign_in` doesn't exist.

What I want to do is to send my route `/:username/:resource_name` right to the bottom of the routes list, so it's the last one to be matched. Is that possible, and does it solve my problem? Or is there another way to get this to work?

Comment: can you post your routes.rb file? and have you tried moving the match statement at the bottom of the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's very possible. The routes file is linear - routes defined first take higher precedence over the ones listed later. Just put that route at the bottom of the file.

Comment: That actually solved my problem! Even though it was so simple, I didn't know because I have only weeks of experience with RoR. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That should do it since the routing file matches top down. See here for a better explanation: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html